# HTML table: same cell size

Tags: html, html-table

I know this should be easy and I've found many threads covering this but I must be missing something. After having tried out a couple of things this is my current code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e97ysbhz/) which should do the trick according to sources. But the cells do not have the same size.

```css
#calendar {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 id='calendar'>
  <tr>
    <td class='calendar_head'>hi</td>
    <td colspan=5 class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
      ---</td>
    <td class='calendar_head'>hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='calendar_day'>Mo</td>
    <td class='calendar_day'>Di</td>
    <td class='calendar_day'>Mi</td>
    <td class='calendar_day'>Do</td>
    <td class='calendar_day'>Fr</td>
    <td class='calendar_day'>Sa</td>
    <td class='calendar_day'>So</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_1'></td>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_2'></td>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_3'></td>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_4'></td>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_5'></td>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_6'></td>
    <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_7'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question. But you can declare the size of the cells with CSS:

Edit: I haven't used the correct percentage. Don't forget that the p tag is 18px in height, so you have to add that in your calculation.

```css
table { 
table-layout: fixed; 
width:100%
}
td {
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table border=1 id='calendar'>
        <tr>
            <td class='calendar_head'>hi</td>
            <td class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
            <td class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
            <td class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
            <td class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
            <td class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
               </td>
            <td class='calendar_head'>hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Mo</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Di</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Mi</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Do</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Fr</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Sa</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>So</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_1'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_2'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_3'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_4'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_5'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_6'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_7'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not want to use px since I need my website to look good on any screen (PC with all sorts of screens, tablets, smartphones, etc ...)

Comment: use percentages then @user3182532

Comment: oh and of course I've tried to add `.calendar_entry{width: (100/7)%; height: (100/3)%;}` to the CSS style. Doesn't work either. EDIT: I replaced `.calendar_entry` with `td` -> still not working

Comment: you can't calculate in CSS without the 'calc()' function; ex."width: calc(100% / 7%);"

Comment: thank you for that hint, I tried `td {width: calc(100/7)%; height: calc(100/3)%;}` but still the cells do not have the same size

Comment: its because you dont have the parent declared in size

Comment: it's still not working: `#calendar{table-layout: fixed; width = 200px; height = 200px;} tr {width = 100%; height = calc(100/3)%;} td {width: calc(100/7)%; height: calc(100/3)%;}`

Comment: you have to use `calc(100%/3)` , I made a typo before

Comment: Chrome treats td { width:calc(...); } as width:auto.

Comment: than use 33.3% for 100/3... just calculate it outside css

Comment: That's unneeded in this case. With table-layout:fixed and no widths specified on the cols or the first row's cells the table width is distributed equally to all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You havent declared a couple of things, such as the parents width

```css
body {width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;} /* this is this parent element of table*/
#calendar{table-layout: fixed;}
table {width: 50%; height: 150px;} /* this is this parent element the table row*/ 
tr {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% / 3);
  line-height: calc(100% / 3);
 }  /* this is this parent element the table data */ 
td.calendar_day {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
}
td.calendar_entry {
   width: calc(100% / 7);
}
td.calendar_entry:empty:before {
 content: "\00a0"; /* unicode zero width space character */
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <table border=1 id='calendar'>
        <tr>
            <td class='calendar_head'>hi</td>
            <td colspan=5 class='calendar_head_month' id='calendar_month'>
                ---</td>
            <td class='calendar_head'>hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Mo</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Di</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Mi</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Do</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Fr</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>Sa</td>
            <td class='calendar_day'>So</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_1'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_2'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_3'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_4'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_5'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_6'></td>
            <td class='calendar_entry' id='calendar_entry_7'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/e97ysbhz/6/

long story short, if you work in percentages, make sure that parents are declared

---

As i explained in comment, the size is determined by it's contents, so what i did to make it "appear" as there is something, hence I applied a little trick in the css.

Comment: but the cells in the last row are still not the same size?

Comment: part of your problem is that the fields are empty. An empty row has no content and in tables, size is partly based on it's content. I updated my awnser btw for you, which now has a height in table row (and a line-height, to play it a bit safe) however, i did base this off a "fixed" variable, which is the height of the table by 200px;

Comment: Chrome ignores calc on internal table parts. Note that if you remove all 4 of your calcs the table looks the same.